# Geth 6.2: miner.start() returns null and miner's hash-rate drop for all miners down due to the update

Tags: go-ethereum

On Geth Version: 1.6.2-unstable `miner.start()` returns null, it used to return number of processes assigned. Is it normal? `miner.start(num)` num identifies the thread number?

```
> miner.stop()
true
> miner.start(4)
null
```

I have a small private net and there is only one miner. The miner used to work for almost couple of months with 503.7 KH/s (since it has been launched with geth v5.9) but now it works with 103.7 KH/s when I updated geth with 6.2 there is this sudden drop down. This drop down affected all the miner's hash rate and I observe that all's hash-rate is drop down around 5 times.

This change occur for my other nodes where hash-rate is get dramatically slower. When I check `top` geth consumes all the CPU power, I assume miner works with full CPU power.

**[Q]** What might be the reason for miner's hash rate drop down (almost 5 times slower)? Could it be related to geth's update on version 6.2? Did anyone faced with similar issue?

**[Q]** This is very inefficient. If the node use much smaller hash-rate why on the background does the CPU consumes all the power? or just hash-rate calculation updated.

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Comment: _Returns null_ basically means that it does not return anything. The javascript console always displays the return value, even if there is none.

Comment: miner.start(n) used to return number of processes assigned on the background. @5chdn

Comment: Both issues might be worth creating a ticket on github.

Comment: Roger that: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14487 @5chdn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14487) has been solved.

@karalabe:

> Missing hashrate was a regression. It was fixed in the latest stable
>   release. Please update. As for the potential slowdown, we did switch
>   out the C++ ethash code to a Go version a couple years back. CPU
>   mining in general is not feasible, so there's not much point in
>   striving to absolute max out performance. A well-enough performing CPU
>   miner is enough for private/testnets.